# How do I prove that $x^2 + y^2 = (x + y) ^2 – 2xy$ geometrically/intuitively?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How do I prove that  $x^2 + y^2 = (x + y) ^2 – 2xy$ geometrically/intuitively?

Background: I teach mid to higher level Singapore maths. It is critical that one can PROVE mathematically every statement/expression. I never introduce any expression just because it works without being able to prove it. For example, difference of two squares, $a^2– b^2$, is proved geometrically by using a drawn square and inner smaller square: one of side $a$ and other of side $b$ and redrawing it to prove that $(a + b)(a – b) = a^2 – b^2$.

But how does one PROVE that 
$$x^2 + y^2 = (x + y)^2  – 2xy?$$

The answers offered so far just introduce $-2xy$ without explaining where it comes from (except as the inverse of $+2xy$).

Remark: I am perfectly aware that 
$$(a + b)^2= a^2  + 2ab + b^2$$
and that one can subtract $2ab$ and it works. But starting with $a^2 + b^2$, how would one know this step mathematically speaking? (I am probably being obtuse, but this is frustrating me!)

Comment: $(x+y)^2 = x^2 + 2xy + y^2 \implies (x+y)^2 - 2xy = x^2 + y^2$.

Comment: _How_ do you know it is correct? Expressing that knowledge step-by-step might be a good way to prove it.

Comment: Substituting integers, I know it works, but I still cannot see how you work back from x squared + y squared = (x + y) squared – 2xy?

Comment: Zannah, you're allowed to start on the right side: Compute $(x + y)^2 = (x +y)(x+y)$, the usual mnemonic being "FOIL". Then subtract $2xy$ from his. You should arrive at the left side, which is perfectly valid.

Comment: Try adding zero (e.g. $2xy-2xy$).$$x^2+y^2=x^2+y^2+2xy-2xy=\dots$$

Answer (score 8):

.........
$$(x+y)^2=x^2+2xy+y^2$$

Comment: I know this expansion, thanks. But, I want to know the proof of x squared +  y squared = ( x + y) squared – 2xy

Comment: Subtract 2xy from both sides.

Answer (score 3):

seems to be what you want.................

[image]

Comment: Thanks a million! And SO obvious, now I look at it. I had a complete 'blank-out' on Friday! My students can now figure out the equation for themselves from this schematic. Question: Did you copy/paste the  diagram and if so how? Thanks again.

Comment: @Zannah, I have an inexpensive scanner at home. It takes just a single page, then can make pdf or jpeg or other. On MSE, it is better to use the jpeg setting. I drew this myself. I draw all my own diagrams, including compass and straightedge constructions.

Comment: Thanks for scanner advice.  So do you then just copy/paste or upload as is? If so, how?  I also do all my own diagramming and super accurate geometric drawings, plus I never give out problems without first doing them myself - in as many alternate ways as possible because everyone thinks/processes differently. Lot of work, but students really appreciate it and removes cause for complaint! Is there a link that teaches 'newbies' how to forma equations on this site correctly? Little time for researching. I REALLY, REALLY appreciate all this advice from strangers.

Comment: @Zannah, upload. Once you create, and name, a jpeg on home computer, on any question or answer there will be a little icon on top (only while editing) of a landscape painting. If you click on that, it asks you to browse for a file, then you open that jpeg as a file. Finally, it asks whether you want to upload that; if you confirm, it places the image in the post you are editing, at the spot where you were just before clicking on the icon. For typesetting it appears you should start at http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation

Comment: Thanks again for succinct information and typesetting links. I have a lot to learn! Hope I can be of some help to you in return, one day.

Answer (score 1):

Multiplication is defined by its distributive property:
$$a (b+c) = a b + a c.$$

So just apply it to $(x+y)^2$:
$$
\begin{split}
(x+y)^2 &= (x+y) x + (x+y) y \\
&= x^2 + x y + x y + y^2 \\
&= x^2 + y^2 + 2 x y.
\end{split}
$$

Comment: Thanks for kind advice. However, I was looking for the geometric schematic proof as shown below.

Comment: Okay, well you should know that that's not an actual proof, it's just a nice schematic meant to help someone grasp it intuitively. So you should have asked something like "how do I intuitively demonstrate that...."

Comment: I beg to differ: it is; and I did ask for geometric/intuitive explanation. Thanks for comment.

Answer (score -2):

Here is an answer (with help from Will Jagy!) that some might like for Grade 7 students or above:
[image]